# Pil or Pillow on Heroku dosen't work

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I tried to migrate my django app to heroku, but Pil library can't work on heroku.
My requirements.txt below works fine on other container based platform, but not on heroku.

```
Django==1.4.6
Pil
django-mptt==0.5.2
...
```

I've checked some QAs on stackoverflow and added some changes and reinstall Pil, Pillow or these some forks below

```
-e hg+https://bitbucket.org/etienned/pil-2009-raclette/#egg=PIL

-e git://github.com/errkk/gitpil.git#egg=PIL
Pillow==1.7.8
```

but doen't work fine with these errors.
'decorder zip not available' 'decoder jpeg not available'.

Do you have any ideas to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Was PIL installed when you tried to install Pillow?

Comment: @Sayse No, I've just installed one of them, Pil or Pillow.